# BeagleBone Black?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone have an image of ROS that I can install?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65173/beaglebone-black?/) by [kurochan917](https://answers.ros.org/users/5155/kurochan917/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-06-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The installation tutorial work for armhf processors (the one used in beagle). You need just to install ubuntu in the board and follow the install steps, http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/UbuntuARM.

---

Originally posted by [Henrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/28087/henrique/) with karma: 68 on 2016-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1